# No Information in Flower connected to amqp on remote machine

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, flower

I have rabbitmq + celery + flower set up on machine A. When I access this flower, I get all the information in the broker, tasks, and workers tabs.

How I start flower on machine A:

`flower --broker=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672// --broker_api=http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/api/`

However, if I set up flower on machine B, but pointing to the first machine A's amqp, i dont get any information. The 3 tabs remain empty.

How I start flower on machine B:

`flower --broker=amqp://guest:guest@machine_A_ip:5672// --broker_api=http://guest:guest@Machine_A_ip:15672/api/`

NB: The manegment-plugin is already enabled.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

[EDIT]
PS: 
With the user account and vhost, it still doesnt work. 
Checked out the logs, and this is what is there:

[I 150112 11:15:13 command:107] Broker: amqp://username:**@[broker ip]:5672/vhapp 

[I 150112 11:15:15 mixins:225] Connected to amqp://username:**@[broker ip]:5672/vhapp
[E 150112 11:16:18 state:71] 
Unable to get broker info: ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out')) 
[E 150112 11:17:50 state:112] Failed to inspect the broker: ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out')) 
[E 150112 11:17:50 state:112] Failed to inspect the broker: ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out')) 
[E 150112 11:17:50 state:112] Failed to inspect the broker: ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out')) 
[E 150112 11:17:50 state:112] Failed to inspect the broker: ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out'))

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that RabbitMQ only allows user "guest" to connect from localhost by default.

Typically you should create a user account specifically for your application. Celery has simple instructions on how to do this here:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html#setting-up-rabbitmq

You can also configure RabbitMQ to allow guest to connect from a remote host, which is discussed here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but even with a different user and vhost, I still dont get any data. It connects properly. But the broker, worker, and tasks tabs are empty. Yet they are populated locally.

Answer (score -1):

I get it.

```
cmd > celery -A task worker
another cmd > celery flower
```

It works.